# I have two lists of numbers. How to generate Random numbers from those lists without repeating the same combination for one that day in flutter

Tags: dart

I have two lists of numbers, One is from 0 to 100 and the other is from 0 to 30. How to generate Random numbers combination from those lists on pressing a button without repeating the same combination for one that day in flutter

```
import 'dart:math';
Num1 = Random().nextInt(100); Num2 = Random().nextInt(30);
DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
DateTime date = new DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
```

On pressing the button on the same day same combination of numbers should not occur.
Example: When button is pressed first time say
`Num1 = 4` and `Num2 = 5`

When button is pressed some other time in the same day, the previous results of `Num1= 4` and `Num2= 5` should not occur.

Please post some logic..thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, there are two different strategies you can do. You can either keep track over pairs you have been generated. Or you can generate all the pairs, keep them in a collection and remove them from this collection when you provide a random pair.

I have created the following example of the last suggested solution:

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  final generator = RandomPairGenerator(maxNum1: 100, maxNum2: 30);

  print(generator.getRandomAndUniquePair()); // (50, 27)
  print(generator.getRandomAndUniquePair()); // (51, 12)
  print(generator.getRandomAndUniquePair()); // (89, 16)
  print(generator.getRandomAndUniquePair()); // (29, 9)
  print(generator.getRandomAndUniquePair()); // (28, 0)
}

class RandomPairGenerator {
  final Queue<Pair> _pairs;

  RandomPairGenerator({required int maxNum1, required int maxNum2})
      : _pairs = Queue.of([
          for (var num1 = 0; num1 < maxNum1; num1++)
            for (var num2 = 0; num2 < maxNum2; num2++) Pair(num1, num2)
        ]..shuffle());

  Pair getRandomAndUniquePair() => _pairs.removeFirst();
}

class Pair {
  final int num1, num2;

  Pair(this.num1, this.num2);

  @override
  String toString() => '($num1, $num2)';
}
```

Instead of calling a random generator for each pair, it is easier to just generate all possible pairs in a `List`, shuffle the `List` and then save them in a `Queue` which are optimized for removing (and adding) elements from either the start or beginning.

### EDIT

Here is an (not very efficient) example of the other approach where we saves the numbers we generates so we don't generates them again:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:quiver/core.dart';

void main() {
  final generator = RandomPairGenerator(maxNum1: 2, maxNum2: 2);

  print(generator.getRandomAndUniquePair()); // (8, 12)
  print(generator.getRandomAndUniquePair()); // (81, 6)
  print(generator.getRandomAndUniquePair()); // (53, 21)
  print(generator.getRandomAndUniquePair()); // (81, 6)
  print(generator.getRandomAndUniquePair()); // (58, 18)
}

class RandomPairGenerator {
  final int maxNum1;
  final int maxNum2;
  final Random _random = Random();
  final Set<Pair> _previousPairs = {};

  RandomPairGenerator({required this.maxNum1, required this.maxNum2});

  Pair getRandomAndUniquePair() {
    Pair pair;

    do {
      pair = Pair(_random.nextInt(maxNum1), _random.nextInt(maxNum2));
    } while (!_previousPairs.add(pair));

    return pair;
  }
}

class Pair {
  final int num1, num2;

  Pair(this.num1, this.num2);

  @override
  String toString() => '($num1, $num2)';

  @override
  int get hashCode => hash2(num1, num2);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      other is Pair && other.num1 == num1 && other.num2 == num2;
}
```

**NOTE:** A major problem with this solution is the runtime cost is going to infinite looping if we try generate more numbers that is possible. The reason is that we actually are just trying to generate a `Pair` and then checks if that `Pair` has already been generated.

The more `Pair` we have generated in the past, the less are available. So the odds of randomly creating a equal on will increase and therefore the need of looping more until we get a unique `Pair`.

I am not sure if we can do much better with that approach unless we do something like my previous solution.

### EDIT 2

I think the best you can do is combine the two solution into something like this:

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:quiver/core.dart';

void main() {
  final generator = RandomPairGenerator(
      maxNum1: 2, maxNum2: 2, previousGenerated: {const Pair(1, 1)});

  print(generator.getRandomAndUniquePair()); // (0, 1)
  print(generator.getRandomAndUniquePair()); // (1, 0)
  print(generator.getRandomAndUniquePair()); // (0, 0)
  print(generator.previousGenerated); // {(1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1)}
  print(generator.getRandomAndUniquePair()); // Exception: No more random Pairs available!
}

class RandomPairGenerator {
  final Set<Pair> _previousGenerated;
  final Queue<Pair> _pairs;

  RandomPairGenerator(
      {required int maxNum1,
      required int maxNum2,
      Set<Pair>? previousGenerated})
      : _pairs = Queue.of([
          ...{
            for (var num1 = 0; num1 < maxNum1; num1++)
              for (var num2 = 0; num2 < maxNum2; num2++) Pair(num1, num2)
          }.difference(previousGenerated ?? {})
        ]..shuffle()),
        this._previousGenerated = previousGenerated ?? {};

  Pair getRandomAndUniquePair() {
    if (_pairs.isEmpty) {
      throw Exception('No more random Pairs available!');
    }

    final pair = _pairs.removeFirst();
    _previousGenerated.add(pair);
    return pair;
  }

  Set<Pair> get previousGenerated => {..._previousGenerated};
}

class Pair {
  final int num1, num2;

  const Pair(this.num1, this.num2);

  @override
  String toString() => '($num1, $num2)';

  @override
  int get hashCode => hash2(num1, num2);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      other is Pair && other.num1 == num1 && other.num2 == num2;
}
```

With this, you can provide a `Set` of already generated `Pair` objects and get a generator which does not generates these. You can also extract a `Set` of all the numbers it has already been generated so you can save this and use next time you need to create a `RandomPairGenerator`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution..When the pairs are generated at some other instance or during some other time in that day there is chance that a pair repeats..

Comment: Instead of generating all the pairs at the beginning and storing in a queue, we can call random pair once and store it in array of list..When button is pressed next time check condition if it has occurred before and then generate another number and store it in the above array..Can we do like this?

Comment: @AzReddy Well, we can never create a generator which protects you from repeating patterns unless we have a central instance which provides said numbers (e.g. a server).  The question about if you should generate all or save the generated is mostly a question about efficiency and how many numbers you are going to generate. But I will give you an example of saving numbers we already have.